# Hibernate JOIN FETCH when no relation exists

Tags: hibernate, join, where-clause, fetch

I have a Customer entity with @OneToMany Account children.
I want perform fetch join to return a customer with its corresponding active accounts (having account.isActive = true). If the customer does not have any accounts it needs to be returned as well.

For the following JPQL, for a customer having inactive accounts, they are indeed filtered out, but a customer without any accounts is not returned:

```
   @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.accounts a WHERE c.id = :id AND a.isActive=true")
```

What would be the clean way to write the query so that both cases would be covered (customer with no accounts and customer with active accounts) ?

Comment: Did you already define the @OneToMany relationship? That is, does Customer have a field that is: "private Set<Account> accounts" ? If so, you can just call customer.getAccounts()

Comment: I need the join fetch in order to retrieve the parent along with the children in a single select. I did define the relationship. Calling customer.getAccounts() would occur anyway later, but it is not related to the question (which is about JPQL/HQL). In the case of no children, there is no customer to call to (it was not retrieved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, answering my own question - the solution was pretty easy:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.accounts a WHERE c.id = :id AND (a is null OR a.isActive=true)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner query:

```
select c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH (select a from accounts a WHERE a.isActive=true) WHERE c.id = :id
```

Comment: This query does not seem to work (apart from the "where and", which i fixed) - I believe this would work for JOIN but JOIN FETCH is a whole different story. Getting "unexpected token" on the left parenthesis after FETCH

Comment: It works on entities I have in my environment. Post the source code of the entities you use.

Comment: Was this the actual query you have used: select c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH (select a from accounts a WHERE a.isActive=true) WHERE c.id = :id